# How do I increase FastCGI read timeout to prevent 504 error on nginx?

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, timeout, gateway, 504

I am running a file with considerable amount of coding. It takes approximately 55 seconds to process 500 users, but now I have to process 1000 users. The default timeout is 60 seconds, so  I have to increase the FastCGI read timeout.

I found [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561946/how-do-i-prevent-a-gateway-timeout-with-nginx) that says I have to increase `fastcgi_read_timeout` but I don't know where to put it in `fastcgi.conf`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you should use `fastcgi_read_timeout`. You can find documentation [here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_read_timeout). According to that, you can specify this parameter either in http, server or location context. So it is also possible to put in into `fastcgi.conf` and include that file where you setup FastCGI.